# OCaml -- how to check if two lists match

Tags: list, ocaml

Say I have two lists:

```
let l1 = [1;2;3];;
let l2 = [1;2;3];;
```

I am trying to check if they have the same values and order, but if I do

```
l1 == l2;;
```

I get false. How do I check if they have the same values in the same order?

Comment: Reminder: `==` checks that the two values point to the same memory address. On non-mutable values, no behavior is guaranteed (and it should only be used in very specific cases, such as hash-consing).

Answer (score 8):

Never mind. I forgot that = was different in OCaml.

```
list1 = list2
```

returns true...